# Was there an app that actually used <icon> , <description> elements of web.xml java ee?

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, web.xml, deployment-descriptor

I'm studying web.xml elements and I see the description group `(icon, description, display-name)` and I was just wondering were these guys ever used like they were supposed to be, like Is there that fancy deployment application that is used to deploy components of web application where you see those icons and move them around ?

---

**Update**, based on the "on hold/opinion based vote" advice, I'm editing my previous question and here's it:

> From Servlet 3.0 Specs page 169:
>
> The icon contains small-icon and large-icon elements that specify the file names
>   for small and large GIF or JPEG icon images used to represent the parent element
>   in a GUI tool.

Does that GUI tool exist ?

Comment: regarding the vote to close "opinion based" I'm asking about the **existence** of an application because I looked and couldn't find one kindly notice which question I have put my question mark on, where is the opinion in that ?, I'm not asking whether they're bad or good